# Use compositeImage to set pixel opacity in a drawing

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Is it possible to do the following:

I have two images, one is a drawing from a canvas in which the background is transparent.  The other is a grayscale drawing where each pixel is either white or black.

I'd like to find a way to set the pixels in the original drawing to full opacity where the black pixels exist in the second image.

I'll provide the input drawings, and what I'd like to get out.  The output is drawn by me, instead I'd like to use `compositeImage`, or other Imagick call to achieve my goal.

Input 1:[image: Input 1]Input 2[image: Input 2]Output[image: Output Image]

Again, they're all .png format, but the intput and output have opacity, where the middle one is grayscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the technique you want to is to composite the two alpha channels, then *copy* the result as the new alpha channel of the original image. For example...

```php
$drawing = new Imagick('drawing.png');
$mask = new Imagick('mask.png');
// Extract original alpha channel from drawing.
$base_opacity = clone $drawing;
$base_opacity->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
// Composite both alpha channels
$base_opacity->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0 ,0);
// Copy new `base_opacity` as alpha channel
$drawing->compositeImage($base_opacity, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0 ,0);
```

Here's a step-by-step preview for the lines above.

```php
// Extract original alpha channel from drawing.
$base_opacity = clone $drawing;
$base_opacity->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
```

[image: base_opacity]

```php
// Composite both alpha channels
$base_opacity->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0 ,0);
```

[image: base_opacity2.png]

```php
// Copy new `base_opacity` as alpha channel
$drawing->compositeImage($base_opacity, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0 ,0);
```

[image: final]

Comment: I was experimenting with different techniques, but none retained the alpha channel from the non-transparent pixels in the original image at the end of the day.  Which worked, but is sub par for what I want.

Your solution is perfect.

Comment: And remember the two alpha channels are basic b/w images that can be [combined in different ways](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/tables/).